# Как не закрывать iOS приложение на .NET MAUI при необработанном исключении?

Tags: .net, ios, maui

Я реализовал глобальный обработчик исключений, который в случае любого необработанного исключения не закрывает приложение, а отображает сообщение пользователю, что произошла какая-нибудь ошибка, после чего приложение продолжает работать.
Это очень удобно, ведь не надо всё оборачивать в try/catch.
На Android и Windows всё работает как надо, но вот на iOS (наверное и на MacOS) приложение просто закрывается, а не продолжает работать.
У меня есть вот такой код, который я подглядел [здесь](https://gist.github.com/mattjohnsonpint/7b385b7a2da7059c4a16562bc5ddb3b7):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (_, args) => (args.ExceptionObject as Exception).DisplayError();
#if ANDROID
Android.Runtime.AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += (sender, args) =>
{
    args.Handled = true;
    args.Exception.DisplayError();
};
#elif WINDOWS
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (_, args) => lastFirstChanceException = args.Exception;
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Application.Current.UnhandledException += (sender, args) =>
{
    Exception exception = args.Exception;
    if (exception.StackTrace == null)
    {
        exception = lastFirstChanceException;
    }
    args.Handled = true;
    args.Exception.DisplayError();
};
#endif
```

Но вот только на iOS это не работает так, как надо, и приложение в любом случае закрывается при любом необработанном исключении.
Немного покопавшись, я нашел нечто, что помогло мне приблизится к ожидаемому результату:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, args) =>
{
    (args.ExceptionObject as Exception).DisplayError();
    #if IOS || MACCATALYST
    Foundation.NSRunLoop.Current.RunUntil(Foundation.NSDate.DistantFuture);
    #endif
};
#if ANDROID
Android.Runtime.AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += (sender, args) =>
{
    args.Handled = true;
    args.Exception.DisplayError();
};
#elif WINDOWS
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (_, args) => lastFirstChanceException = args.Exception;
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Application.Current.UnhandledException += (sender, args) =>
{
    Exception exception = args.Exception;
    if (exception.StackTrace == null)
    {
        exception = lastFirstChanceException;
    }
    args.Handled = true;
    args.Exception.DisplayError();
};
#endif
```

После добавления `Foundation.NSRunLoop.Current.RunUntil(Foundation.NSDate.DistantFuture)` всё стало работать почти так, как надо. При необработанном исключении действительно отображается сообщение с ошибкой, при этом приложение продолжает работать!
Но есть один нюанс... Это работает лишь один раз! Если произойдёт второе необработанное исключение, то приложение просто закроется.
Способ, который я нашёл, это просто какой-то костыль, который я нашел [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39185094/21052018). Причём другие способы не оказали никакого эффекта. Вот я и решил спросить у вас, знает ли кто, что мне делать в такой ситуации.

Comment: А просто исправить баг в программе не вариант?

Comment: Гений, я по вашему должен оборачивать абсолютно каждый метод в try/catch? Да и про какой баг идёт речь, когда его нет.

Comment: Нет, поймать и подавить исключение — это не исправление бага, это игнор бага. Я бы порекомендовал найти причину, по которой бросается исключение, и устранить её.

Comment: Боже, вы хоть прочитали, что я вам ответил? Нету никакого бага, я сделал это всё для того, чтобы не надо было оборачивать сотни методов в абсолютно одинаковый try/catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я ничего толкового не нашёл в интернете, а если и находил, то там лишь говорили, что приложение в любом случае закроется.
После небольших тестов я понял, что `Foundation.NSRunLoop.Current.RunUntil(Foundation.NSDate.DistantFuture)` можно заменить на `Foundation.NSRunLoop.Current.Run()`, а так же, что этот метод не завершает свою работу, пока не произойдёт другая ошибка.
То есть метод, который вызывается в событии `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` будет работать вечно, вызывая самого себя, будет что-то типа рекурсии, из-за чего ошибка во второй раз не будет отображена пользователю и приложение закроется.
Ну и я решил зайти в **Platforms/IOS/Program.cs** и написать там это:

```
public sealed class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool launching = true;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                if (launching)
                {
                    launching = false;
                    UIApplication.Main(args, null, typeof(AppDelegate));
                }
                else NSRunLoop.Current.Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.DisplayError();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

То есть, когда приложение только запускается, то вызывается `UIApplication.Main`, который отрисовывает приложение, а когда происходит исключение, то мы его ловим, затем отображаем пользователю, после чего отрисовкой приложения занимается `NSRunLoop.Current.Run` и так идёт по кругу.
Это единственный рабочий вариант, но не без подвоха!
Подвох заключается в том, что исключение может произойти в момент того, как отрисовывается какой-нибудь UI-элемент, из-за чего он просто сломается, например: если во время навигации на какую-нибудь страницу где-нибудь произойдёт исключение, то кнопка навигации назад перестанет работать правильно и при нажатии на неё приложение зависнет. Это значит, что придётся проводить дополнительные махинации, чтобы всё это вернуть на круги своя.
На Windows и Android это не происходит, то есть это побочный эффект данного обходного путя.
Ну а подпись на событие `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` в билдах для iOS и MacOS можно исключить из-за ненадобности.